# Bootstrap 4.3 - how to position an image with position-absolute but to the right and a specific height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFbbt.jpg)I am converting files with Bootstrap **4.0** CSS to Bootstrap **4.3** CSS.

I have a price section that contains 3 pricing panels. One of which has an image with a position absolute class and pixel positioning classes `- l-100 t-25`.

`<img class="position-absolute l-100 t-25 centered" src="images/gallery/primary.png">`

Bootstrap **4.3** has `.position-fixed` with `.fixed-top` or `.fixed-bottom` but `.position-absolute` seems not to have any positioning CSS.

I have looked through the Bootstrap **4.3** website and all over google and can not find a class to replace the old positioning, short of creating a specific style myself. Can anyone help?

Please see image of price panel with graphic in position on the right-hand side

Answer (score 0):

First of all bootstrap 4.3 does have the following positioning css for class `position-absolute`

```
.position-absolute {
    position: absolute!important
}
```

Ref: https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

Still, If you are facing issues positioning elements using bootstrap, I recommend using **flexbox**. It is much cleaner and easier to use.

You will find the complete guide [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: yes I know there is .position-absolute in 4.3, you haven't understood my question. Its seems you can no longer position an item in the exact position without creating a style independent of Bootstrap 4.3. As I said I can code left and top (eg. l-100 t-25) in 4.0 but not in 4.3

Comment: why do you want to use bootstrap if you can use flex

Comment: my understanding is that you can't position an image precisely with flex in the manner I want. I want to position an image over the top of a div eg position-absolute; top:20px: right: -20px - I have added a layout of what I mean